# Excel sum only single or first duplicated value in a list

Tags: excel, countif

I've a formula in Excel which I've found on the net which gives the required result but I don't fully understand how it works. This is `=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B9/COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9))` and the result is `129` for the following data (it adds single occurrences in Column `B` of the data, this being `13 + 24 + 92 = 129` which is the required result).

```
Row  A  B
1    1  13
2    1  13
3    1  13
4    1  13
5    3  24
6    3  24
7    3  24
8    12 92
9    12 92
```

I understand the `COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9)` is creating an array `{4;4;4;4;3;3;3;2;2)` but I don't know how the range `B1:B9` numerator is working to create the result. If the numerator was say the number "1" (i.e. the formula being instead `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9))`, the result is `3` and I think is worked out as the sum of `1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/2 + 1/2`. So how when the `B1:B9` is in the formula how step by step is it working it out?

Comment: https://support.office.com/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close to the answer yourself. Given your example you have two arrays:
The first one is the numbers from column B and the other one from the countif in column A:
{13;13;13;13;24;24;24;92;92} and {4;4;4;4;3;3;3;2;2}

In the sumproduct formula you have the division and therefore you get the arrays divided:
{13/4; 13/4; 13/4; 13/4; 24/3; 24/3; 24/3; 92/2; 92/2} and the sum of these numbers are:
3,25 + 3,25 + 3,25 + 3,25 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 46 + 46 = **129**

And there is the magic number :-)

Comment: Brilliant! Perfect explanation. As you say, I was quite close. Thanks very much.